# prevent form submission when all input text fields are empty but allow submission when any of them in not empty with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, input, laravel-4

The scenario is that I have a form with dynamic multiple text field.

```
<form id="add" action="" method="POST">
  <input type="text" id="product-$id" name="quantity[]" class="quantity" />
</form>
```

depending on condition it generates multiple input fields. It looks like this

```
<form id="add" action="" method="POST">
<input type="text" id="product-1" name="quantity[]" class="quantity" />
<input type="text" id="product-2" name="quantity[]" class="quantity" />
<input type="text" id="product-3" name="quantity[]" class="quantity" />
    </form>
```

Now I want to prevent my form submission if all of the text fields are empty.
But I will allow form submission if any of them have a value.

Comment: why don't you use jquery validation http://jqueryvalidation.org/ its not that hard.

Comment: Looking into that...

Answer (score 0):

I hope the following code will give you an idea on how to proceed.

```
function SubmitForm(){

     //get all the dynamic textbox in the form
      var quantities =$('#add').find('.quantity');
      var hasValue = false;

      $.each(quantities, function(i, txtbox)
        {
           if ($.trim($(txtbox).val()) != '')
             {
               hasValue = true;
               return false; //break
               }
        });

        if (!hasValue)
          {
            return; //do not proceed further
            }

      //code here as atleast one textbox has a value

}
```